# searborn: maintain the order of palette color in legend

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I make several plots my data using [seaborn's displot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.displot.html). I cutomise the palette using the dictionary:

```py
my_palette = {'car': 'b', 'foot':'k', 'metro':'c', 'bus':'r', 'bike':'y'} # values of hue
```

And then plot like so:

```py
# fig customisation omitted for brevity
sns.displot(df1, x='distance', kind='ecdf', hue='mode', log_scale=True, palette=my_palette,)
```

Giving:

[image]

But then when I plot the next figure, the legend order change (as python dictionary isn't ordered), like this one:

```py
sns.displot(df2, x='distance', kind='ecdf', hue='mode', log_scale=True, palette=my_palette,)
```

Which gives:

[image]

I am wondering if there's a way to maintained a defined ordering, such as `foot, bike, bus, car, metro`

Comment: You could set a fixed order with `df1["mode"] = pd.Categorical(df1["mode"], ["foot", "bike", "bus", "car", "metro"])` and similar for `df2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `hue_order` base order that you want and keys of your `my_palette` dict.

```
sns.displot(df2, x='distance', kind='ecdf', hue='mode', 
            log_scale=True, palette=my_palette,
            hue_order=['foot', 'bike', 'bus', 'car', 'metro']
            )
```

from [`doc`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.displot.html):

> hue_order:
> Specify the order of processing and plotting for categorical levels of the hue semantic.